# msxml 6.0 for wine

Tags: 12.04, wine, microsoft-office, winetricks

I have trying to install an application to Ubuntu 12.04 via Winetrics. However, I have got below error.

```
   this msxml 6.0 is not supported on the current processor type
```

I have searched google to fix this error, but I could nor manage it. Thus, How can I fix it ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a problem with the installer ; it is attempting to install the 32-bit version of MSXML (the Microsoft XML library) on a 64-bit machine (or vice versa).

The first part of the solution to this is to install the correct version for your machine. The downloads list is [here](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=3988) ; the x64 version is probably what you need.

Alas, unless the vendor supplies an x64 package, or will supply a package without MSXML bundled, or unless you open the package and tinker with it (in a tool like Orca, the MSI database editor), this is where the story ends. It's a shame MSI packages are so difficult to work with ; unlike .DEB which is just a fancy archive, MSI is a database (or a *very* fancy archive).

The other path is to consider installing a native package that provides the features you wanted out of the Windows software.